# Pegar nome parcial de um processo

Tags: c#, .net, string, winforms, processo

Existe alguma forma que eu possa conseguir pegar um processo que esteja rodando por um nome parcial, tipo o que acontece com o `like` em uma pesquisa `SQL`?

Porque pergunto isso: Tenho um *`team viewer`* personalizado aqui para a empresa. Só que a versão que temos aqui é a 10. Beleza até ai sem problemas... O que acontece é que, se por acaso tiver algum processo com o nome de "Team Viewer 10", eu posso *matar* ele. Só que se o cliente tiver uma versão mais recente ou anterior, o nome do processo não é o mesmo... Então não teria como *matar*.

Então teria como eu pegar o nome do processo de forma parcial e se encontrado, matar? Ou seja, se eu encontrar um processo com o nome "Team Viewer", já acionar o código para *matar* esse processo?

O que eu tenho até agora:

```
 //buscando o nome do processo
        System.Diagnostics.Process[] processoTv = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName(teamViewer);

        //verificando se existe o processo em execução e se houver finaliza
        if (processoTv.Length > 0)
            foreach (System.Diagnostics.Process processoItem in processoTv)
                processoItem.Kill();
```

Onde `teamViewer` é igual a "Team Viewer 10".

Será que existe alguma forma de fazer isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Pegue todos os processos](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.getprocesses?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Diagnostics_Process_GetProcesses) e [filtre manualmente](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_String_Contains_System_String_):

```
Process[] processoTv = Process.GetProcesses(); //variável só necessária se pretente usar mais tarde
foreach (var processoItem in processoTv) if (processoItem.ProcessName.Contains(teamViewer)) processoItem.Kill();
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Enviroment/GetProcessNamePartial.cs).

Não sei todas as implicações de fazer isto. Esta é a base, mas pode ter alguma coisa que pode dar alguma problema, não li toda a documentação, que é algo que todo programador deve fazer antes de usar qualquer coisa. Não fiz porque não é algo que eu vou usar, mas está aí a ressalva.

Aproveitei para simplificar o código. Dá para fazer o filtro com LINQ também, mas não compensa porque depois terá que realizar o `foreach`.

Comment: `Process[] processoTv = Process.GetProcesses(); //variável só necessária se pretente usar mais tarde`.... Mais tarde como? Tipo se quero verificar os processos rodando em algum momento?

Comment: Variável essencialmente deve ser usada para criar um estado intermediário. Embora eventualmente seja útil criar uma variável para usar apenas uma vez, em geral, isto não é necessário. Claro que se algo for muito complicado é bom criar uma variável só para documentar, mas é raro. Se vai usar aquilo apenas uma vez no algoritmo, não crie uma variável só para isso, use a expressão direto. A maioria dos programadores não entendem o uso da variável, que é um dos recursos mais básicos do código. O problema talvez sejam os exemplos que para serem didáticos colocam redundância. Não á para copiar.

Comment: eu consegui resolver usando sua solução! Muito Obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Pode tentar isso:

```
  foreach (var process in System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses())
        {
            if (process.ProcessName.Contains("Team Viewer"))
            {
                process.Kill();

            }

        }
```

Comment: Boa solução! Muito obrigado!